# DevExpress exportToXls NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, devexpress, export-to-excel

There was an Exception when I used DevExpress to export my data to an excel file:

```
GridControl gridControl2 = new GridControl();
gridControl2.DataSource = exportDataList; // my data list

SaveFileDialog fileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
fileDialog.Title = "Data Export";
fileDialog.Filter = "Excel (2010) (.xlsx)|*.xlsx|*.xls|*.csv";
DialogResult dialogResult = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    gridControl2.ExportToXls(fileDialog.FileName);  // NullReferenceException
```

but I newed GridControl before, and the file path i think it's ok, so i don't understand why this exception happened, anyone could tell me? thanks

Comment: Which DevExpress for WinForms version you're using? Is the exception occurred in all machines or just other machines than used for development?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto My DevExpressUniversal version is 15.2.4.But I just resolved this exception by create a GridView: new a gridView2 and let gridView2.GridControl = gridControl2;And now, there is another question...the result that i exported was null(I mean the data in the excel file is empty)...I think it may because something wrong with my `gridView2`.still need help..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your code snippet, you have created the GridControl instance In-the-Air(without parenting it at any visual container). This is not typical usage for any Windows Forms control. In this case, the Grid's lifecycle(initialization, handle creation, painting etc.) is not started at all.
**You can force the grid control to finish its initialization** via the [GridControl.ForceInitialize](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.ForceInitialize.method) method call. After the grid control has been initialized, you can manipulate its settings safely.

Using the visual control to accomplishing the exporting/conversion tasks is a kind of hack/trick. The much-preferred solution is using the special exporting tools for this task.
DevExpress provides the [Office File API](https://documentation.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/14911/Office-File-API) which is a non-visual cross-platform .NET library for document processing. You can work with rich-text documents, spreadsheets or reports, draw barcodes, create new or edit existing PDF documents, convert different units and compress data directly from code, without any UI components, such as the Grid Control or Spreadsheet.
Thus, I suggest you start from here: [Spreadsheet Document API > Getting Started](https://documentation.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/15072/Spreadsheet-Document-API/Getting-Started)

Comment: Thank u very much!